# Facebook login upon QR scan

Tags: facebook, url, redirect, authentication, qr-code

I'd like to redirect a user to my facebook events page when they scan a QR code. HOwever, when the QR code is scanned I am redirected to a login page on my mobile. Is it possible to redirect to the specific event page?

thanks
-k-

Answer (score 0):

Just send them to this url: http://m.facebook.com/EVENT_ID

Such as:

http://m.facebook.com/371939689563437

Comment: no luck, when I use the url in the format above I'm still redirected to the facebook login page.

Comment: Correct. In all my experiences, in order to see an event page on mobile, the user must be logged in. Theres a ton of privacy settings that if one of them are turned on, the user must be logged in to see it.

Comment: Got it. So the only way I can redirect them to my events page without them having to log-in is if I change my privacy settings?

Comment: Perhaps, try it and see what happens